# ¿Cómo detectar colisiones exactas entre 2 objetos en Java?

Tags: java

Asi como en Game maker Studio que hay una opcion de colisiones exactas para que los objetos colisionen solo cuando una parte de la imagen con color de un objeto colisiona con otra parte de la imagen con color, 
en java yo utilizo:

```
if(new Rectangle(x,y,ancho,alto).intersects(new Rectangulo(objeto.x, objeto.y, objeto.ancho, objeto.alto)){
   //Colisiono
}
```

pero esto solo detecta un rectangulo formado alrededor de los objetos y yo quiero que enves de rectangulos, la colision se detecte hasta donde comience el color de la imagen sin tomar en cuenta espacios vacios.

Si es que se puede.

Comment: Que objetos utilizas? Si utilizas Shape esta respuesta te puede servir: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690846/java-collision-detection-between-two-shape-objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe un método en Java que hace lo que quieres(colisión de polígonos) funciona con la clase Shape `shape.getBounds2D().intersects(other.getBounds2D())`, pero es algo complejo manejar esa clase porque tendrías que detallar los puntos que quieres que conformen la figura.

Por otra parte para evaluar las colisiones tienes otras opciones:

- Puedes usar círculos en vez de rectángulos, para  saber si dos círculos están colisionando es muy fácil: si la suma de sus radios es mayor que la distancia entre sus centros entonces existe colisión.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Puedes hacer un método que verifique la colisión entre lineas y polígonos.
- Puedes guardar todos los puntos de las figuras en una matriz y evaluar la colisión punto por punto.

Recuerda que entre más precisa la evaluación de la colisión más recursos computacionales sera utilizados(incluso existen muchos algoritmos más que puedes consultar), así que si quieres dejarlo simple sigue con los rectángulos.

Fuentes: [GenbetaDev](https://www.genbetadev.com/programacion-de-videojuegos/teoria-de-colisiones-2d-conceptos-basicos)